# Subsurf adaptive on smoke?

Tags: smoke-simulation, subdivision-surface

I have a big smoke simulation that's all baked and has been rendering for awhile. I just saw Blender Guru's video about adaptive subserf and was curious to know if it's possible to apply this to physics. It would save me a tremendous amount of time If I could render on my GPU!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Adaptive Subsurf* is meant to change density of a mesh (as regular *Subsurf*). You can't control smoke by this as smoke is a *Volume* simulation.

Comment: Shoot. Forgive me for sounding like an idiot!

Comment: If you ask me I think this was good way of thinking, something like adaptive smoke would be really great. But then I see that the whole sim should take a place and then some tesselation could be done. So this is pretty pointless.